# How do you remove network server 'servername.local'?

Tags: networking, server, smb

My Ubuntu 18.10 has an original smb network server named, 'servername'. There is also a second named, 'servername.local', which may have been created from Rhythmbox plugin DAAP music share having been turned on. Each are identical, containing my shared folders. I've since turned DAAP off but the second server 'servername.local' remains. How can I remove it? My `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` is identical to another 18.10 on my network, which does not have this duplicate issue. So I don't know where else to look.

EDIT: I'm not quite sure how else to ask it: how would I remove the 'servername.local' server? Anyone?

Comment: Do you have a ".service" file at /etc/avahi/services that references daap or rhythmbox?

Comment: @Morbius1 No, nothing is in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how DNS works. `servername` and `servername.local` both point to the SAME server. The `.local` domain is specified in `/etc/resolv.conf` with the `search local` directive.

On MY system,

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ host bat
bat.localdomain has address 192.168.100.90
walt@bat:~(0)$ host bat.local
bat.localdomain has address 192.168.100.90
walt@bat:~(0)$ less /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search local
```

Like it says, read `man resolv.conf;man resolvconf` (`man resolver` if you're programming)

Comment: Thanks @waltinator. Am I supposed to have both server names then? My 18.10 laptop only has `laptopname.local`--not `laptopname`. On this 18.10 desktop, it has both `desktopname.local` and `desktopname`. I guess I don't understand why the difference between them, or if it will cause any problem.